# How does django handle cached_property invalidation in a request/response cycle?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a model with a [cached property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = fields.Charfield()

    @cached_property
    def count_friends(self):
        return self.friends_set.count()
```

Django states that:

> The cached result will persist as long as the instance does, so if the instance is passed around and the function subsequently invoked, the cached result will be returned.

How does this means `cached_property` works in the request/response cycle? For example, if I only use `object.count_friends` in a template, will it be refreshed each time the view is called (assuming browser cache is cleared!)?

Have I understood this correctly? E.g. each time I make a call to the DB, I assume it's refreshed?

In what practical circumstances would it not be refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@cached_property`s are cached per-instance. The request-response cycle has no bearing on this (unless you stow away models as e.g. global variables **which you shouldn't do** or in the Django cache, ...)

```
def my_view(request):
    m = MyModel.objects.get(id=42)
    x = m.count_friends  # causes a DB access
    x = m.count_friends  # does not cause a DB access
    m = MyModel.objects.get(id=42)
    x = m.count_friends  # causes a DB access
    x = m.count_friends  # does not cause a DB access
```

Comment: Thanks, so each time the same view is called it should refresh the db from L3 in your example? E.g. if I use `m.count_friends` in another view, it still refreshes because it's called in the view?

Comment: It doesn't really depend on view, could be any old function. So long as you pass the same `m` around, it'll reuse the cached value after the first retrieval. The queryset `get` method always returns a fresh instance.